# Failure retrieving Diagnostics Logs location

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, uls

I've been getting these Unexpected ULS entries from `Timer Job hourly-all-sptimerservice-health-analysis-job`:

> Failure retrieving Diagnostics Logs location:
>   System.ArgumentException: Object must be a root directory ("C:\") or a drive letter ("C").
>   at System.IO.DriveInfo..ctor(String
>   driveName)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Health.AppServerDrivesAreNearlyFull. 
>   GetDrivesForValidation()

Does anyone know what is this about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you change the default Diagnostics Logs location? By default, SharePoint log files are saved to the following location: "C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS".

From the error message, it showed there was something wrong with the logs location, check it and make sure it matches the correct format.

[Configure diagnostic logging in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-diagnostic-logging)

Comment: Your answer is correct. Trace log path has to be set to "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\LOGS".

Comment: Here's an extra analysis why this error has happened: https://slavensemper.blogspot.com/2019/09/failure-retrieving-diagnostics-logs.html